# How can I create a zooming, panning gesture control panel in xaml for windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 8, Is there a control that I can add Rectangles and other shapes to and have it respond to pinching and swiping to make it pan and zoom? Please note that the Toolkit.GestureService is now deprecated.

I have tried all the controls available and none seem to work correctly.

I tried wrapping a canvas in a  but then it does not respond to Pinch gestures.

I have tried many samples from across the net and they all have their own specific problems.

The Panel will be larger than the Phones screen width and height. maybe 700 x 600.
It will have Shapes like Rectangle on it.
I need to change the "Scale" or Zoom of it by pinching.
I need to be able to Pan it by swiping left, right, up, or down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is well documented in MSDN

[Input for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff607287%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)